# Ratio of $A:B$ given their weighted average

Tags: word-problem, ratio

Adult tickets cost $9$ dollars and child tickets cost $3$. A total of $400$ tickets were sold, and the **average profit per sale** ($1$ ticket sold at a time) was $\$3.45$. How many **times** more child tickets were sold than adult tickets?

This is a simplified version of my actual question which would take too long to explain. I don't know if this can be answered but I'm effectively trying to find the ratio of child to adult tickets given the weighted average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the proportion of adult tickets. Then
$$
9p + 3(1-p) = 3.45 .
$$
Can you find $p$ now?

When you know $p$ can you find the ratio of child to adult tickets? (Assume there are $100$ of them if necessary).

Comment: Yup, that clicked for me. I was thinking of it as a ratio, where it's really a proportion...

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept the answer (the check mark), upvote if you wish (the up arrow) or post an answer to your own question, or all of the above.